# How to further dim the screen for Windows 8.1 Metro interface?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, tablet, brightness

For using the tablet in a dark room, I am trying to set my screen dimmer than the lowest brightness setting that windows provides. Just like you would use screen filter in Android devices.

So far I have only found 2 portable apps that does this:

- [Dimmer](http://www.nelsonpires.com/software/dimmer/)
- [DimScreen](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/index.html#DimScreen)

However, while they do dim the screen, it only dims the normal desktop applications. Once I switched to Metro interface, the screen still shows as its normal brightness.

Is there a way to dim the metro interface screen brightness dimmer than the windows lowest brightness setting?

Comment: "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research. Here are a few suggestions on how to properly ask this type of question."  You could [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/719953/edit) your question to be more on-topic by asking just "how to do I accomplish this", rather than "I need a tool to..."

Comment: I do think I shared my research, described my situation and put in a certain amount of effort. Of course I googled, but the hot results from things like `"windows rt brightness dim "` only gives you how to disable auto brightness or the usual windows setting. I need something that can "FURTHER" dim the screen, and the tool I found so far does not work for Metro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) to adjust your display settings, those settings carry over to metro apps (or UI apps or Windows Store apps, or whatever you want to call them) as well. Not only can you adjust the color temperature (or not), you can also lower the brightness a few ticks by hitting Alt-PgDn. It won't dim things as much as Dimmer or DimScreen, but I've found it to be sufficient.

Note that this information is current as of December 2014 and f.lux version 3.10.

Comment: I tried it.. But it does not fit my need. I wish the screen to be darker, instead of warmer ( lower color temperature ). But good to know this kind of app existed..

Comment: That's weird, on my version of f.lux you can lower the brightness (with Alt-PgDn) without it changing the color temperature. Sorry to hear that didn't work for you but if I learn of any other solutions I'll post them here.

Comment: It worked! It worked! I just had not read the fxx menu!